# Plain form as imperative

Tags: imperatives

Is the plain form ever used to give a command? What does "sugu ni tatsu" mean?

[image: sugu ni tatsu]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, 終止形 can be used as a command like in this manga. Translation: "Then stand up right away!"

It sounds like a parent or a school teacher ordering their kids to do something right away. It's weaker/friendlier than 立て but stronger than 立ってください.

Such use of 終止形 is not usually heard in military organizations, so I feel the person on the right is being rather friendly rather than dignified as a supervisor.

Negative form is also possible. Example: 「(教室で先生が)そこ、喋らない！」「ごちゃごちゃ反論しない！」

Comment: Rather than being weaker / stronger, I would say it is a more / less direct way of addressing (which by consequence may feel more or less strong). Maybe it's just my feeling though, I haven't checked it.