# I was told to do X if Y

Tags: translation, expressions

I have no idea how to translate this sentence pattern into Japanese.
If I try with basic grammar, it sounds very wrong and overly complex.

What is the most natural way of expressing this? If there is a more business version, please share it as well.

For example

> - 電話が鳴ったら早く電話に出ると言われました
> - それが出来ると課長に報告してと言われました.

Comment: Would you be willing to show us the phrases/sentences that sound very wrong and overly complex to you?

Comment: 電話が鳴ったら早く電話に出ると言われました / それが出来ると課長に報告してと言われました. But we'll end up focusing on my very low Japanese instead of answering the question about possible patterns to express what I want to express. Although I would never be relunctant to any help on those sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid using quoted speech, the common idiom worth memorizing is **"Xするよう(に)言う"**.

Your translation attempt is not bad, but here are a few comments:

- In the first example, are you intentionally using [the plain form 出る as an imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15816/5010)? That makes sense, but it's better to simply use the imperative form 出ろ.
- No need to say 電話 twice.
- In the second example, this それ is usually omitted.
- Replace 出来ると with 出来たら. Explaining the difference between と and たら is difficult for me, but you can see this page: [Conditionals | Learn Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals)

How about these?

> - 電話が鳴ったら早く出ろと言われました。
> - 電話が鳴ったら早く出るように言われました。
> - 出来たら課長に報告してと言われました。
> - 出来たら課長に報告するよう言われました。

Comment: In the first example, are you intentionally using the plain form 出る as an imperative?  -> No, if I paused before submiting this sentence I would probably have changed it to 出て :(