# Do Japanese use 順番、順番！ as a command, like in the military?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jp6trk9Ljs&t=3m41s

何のためのくじ引きだと思ったんだ ？

はい、はい！順番、順番！？

はい、 A 組以外は、はい、 戻る !

Or did I misunderstand these sentences?

Comment: Nice understandable question, only replied directly re Turn, turn!, though, as it wasn't clear if the other text was intended as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike 戻る (which is a [plain-form imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15816/5010)), 順番 by itself is not a direct command to make someone move. In this video, the teacher simply reminded the students that there was something called 順番 that they needed to respect. Semantically, this "順番!" is more like "Remember 順番!".

Likewise, we don't say "順番!" in militaristic contexts. A normal drill command to make people line up is "整列!" ("Fall in!").

Comment: Thanks! This was very confusing for me, until you guys all helped out.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in the title 順番、順番！on its own, Turn , turn!, except in an unusual context, such as a response in a classroom as to what this word is, etc, wouldn't likely be used, since it's a noun. For an imperative, a verb meaning to turn and with the word ending for the 'imperative tense' would be used.

Comment: Please consider the friendly tag & the 'Code of Conduct'! Just noticed a downvote after merely a few minutes! Yet not any comment or offered helpful suggestion or attempt to improve this answer, nor to answer the question! As the Asker seems to be asking in English! Apologies if the English in this answer isn't perfect! Merely attempting to offer a helpful answer for the Asker, & included qualifiers for when the question text might be seen; And zero attempt to answer the question or help: A helpful suggestion re this post would be appreciated, & beneficial to this SE site. Sorry. Thank you.

Comment: @ M H thanks for the reply! Any reply is better than no reply, as I always say!

Comment: どうもありがとうございます/ Thank You very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

"順番！"

Taking Turns! = Kids on a slide など (everyone wants to go)

Everyone Goes! = Kids lining up to get vaccine (nobody wants to go)

Used by: Someone in authority (Mom, Teacher, Coach)

順番 is not turn however, it is an idea referring to order, an order of steps, or it could be turns for people. note in kanji we have 書き順.

As for military usage, well perhaps in some instances, though is seem odd that is would need to be shouted at soldiers, as discipline should be their domain.

Comment: @ Reed Day thanks for the response! I am always grateful for any input from members.