# Why do people say "食べる" instead of "食べましょう" or "食べよう"

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, spoken-language, volitional-form

From what I understand, "**食べましょう**" and "**食べよう**" both imply, more or less, the same meaning, which is '*to invite someone to eat with them*', the latter being a verb conjugation of the volitional form, the more casual 'ましょう'.

However, "**食べる**", the base verb which means '*to eat*', is much more commonly used for the invitation message. I would like to know why that is so, and when have people started to use it, so much so, that is has become a colloquial phenomenon.

Thank you.

Comment: `Much more commonly used` according to whom?  I completely disagree with that.

Comment: @istrasci op maybe talking about this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlY-Qdc52vU not sure about it being more common or not... the same teacher has a whole lesson about よう use for inviting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, "食べる", the base verb which means 'to eat', is much more commonly used for the invitation message.

No. 食べる is **not** used as an invitation like ～ましょう/～よう, both of which roughly mean "Let's eat it". The plain form is used in the following situations:

- To state the speaker's own will

  > 食べる!
  > I'll eat it!
- As a question to check someone's will (used with a rising intonation)

  > 食べる? ⤴
  > Wanna eat?

  (Note that this **can** sometimes work as a casual invitation, but basically it's just a question.)
- Less commonly, as an imperative (used by a parent, teacher, etc. [Plain form as imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15816/5010))

  > 食べる!
  > Eat it!