# Can the plain form of a verb ever mean an instruction or suggestion?

Tags: verbs

Like on GUI prompts you see phrases like

> メニューを閉める

Since this the plain form of the verb, it should mean that "someone/something closes/will close". It can't ever be an instruction right? So why don't they write

> メニューを閉めて

or even

> メニューを閉めろ

So does this mean that sentences like

> 本をちゃんと読む

can sometimes be interpreted to be instructions or suggestions to read your book properly?

Comment: I have never thought of 'Read more' on a website in English as an imperative in English

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15816/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, I'm not sure if 'Close' in English is an imperative, but in Japanese 終止形(dictionary form) can be used to give instructions or orders.

Example 1: A mother may say to her child: さっさと食べて学校に行く = Eat quickly and go to school.

Example 2: An instruction to prepare cup noodle: 1. お湯を注ぐ Pour hot water 2. 3分待つ Wait for 3 mins.