# Does はやく give the sentence the nuance of a order?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

> はやく
> もう入れる。。。から

The character is standing in front of a wardrobe with something in his hands and the other character tells him this.

From context the only thing I can gather is "Hurry up and put the thing in", but why?

Comment: Sentence with [終止形]{しゅうしけい} / Conclusive form can have imperative meaning even without はやく, see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15816/ and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97686/.

Answer (score 2):

Simply yes. It may be simlar to *Quick*, which works as an imperative without *be*.

You can think there is しろ or して omitted after はやく. (はやくして/はやくしろ sounds stronger).